# ReactJs, storing user inputs as a new object in an empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to store in an empty array a user input and a unique id as an object.

So I have:

```
const [weight, setWeight] = useState([]);
```

that I want to fill with this function:

```
const submitWeight = () => {
    setWeight([{ value: inputWeight, id: uuidv4() }, ...weight]); // this one.
    setDefaultMessageWeight("");
    closedClass();
  };
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: What is the issue with your current code?

Comment: When calling the function, I crash the whole app and get a white screen with this error in the console: "Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {value, id})."

Comment: That error is related to what you are returning from your function (ie: your JSX), not the code you've shown here

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can access a rendered input element using `ref` inside your component.

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [weight, setWeight] = useState([]);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const submitWeight = () => {
    let inputWeight = inputRef.current.value;
    setWeight([{ value: inputWeight, id: uuidv4() }, ...weight]); 
    // ... 
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={inputRef} />

      <button onClick={submitWeight}>Submit</button>

      {weight.map(({ value }, index) => (
        <p>
          Weight #{index} is {value}
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```